# Using renderToNodeStream with react-helmet

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-helmet

I am currently creating a website and have been looking to start using `renderToNodeStream` to increase the performance of the server side rendering instead of using `renderToString`.

At the moment I am using `renderToString` and then using `Helmet.renderStatic` to get all the required meta data and title from each of the pages. When I switch to using `renderToNodeStream` however, I will be writing to the head prior to rendering anything, and so can no longer use `Helmet.renderStatic` anymore.

I was thinking I could do the below to solve this issue, but this involves first using `renderToString` before then using `renderToNodeStream`, and probably doesn't really provide much improvement...

```
app.use('*', (req, res) {
  Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
    const store = createStore(
      reducers,
      getDefaultStateFromProps(),
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
    const routeContext = {};
    const router = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routeContext}>
          <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    renderToString(router);
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

    res.locals.title = helmet.title;
    res.locals.meta = helmet.meta;
    res.locals.link = helmet.link;

    res.write(headTemplate(res.locals));

    const stream = renderToNodeStream(router);

    stream.pipe(res, { end: false });
    stream.on('end', () => {
      res.locals.context = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
      res.end(bodyTemplate(res.locals));
    });
  });
}
```

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: Hey Phil, did you manage to solve the issue you were facing with this? We are just about to look at using `renderToNodeStream`

Comment: here is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050007/react-ssr-blinks-when-starting-client) for more info and help

Answer (score 8):

This has been an issue I have also been struggling with lately -- I've been trying to migrate an app from renderToString to renderToNodeStream and was having a heck of a time trying to get dynamic head data to work.

So, unfortunately `react-helmet` doesn't provide out of the box support for renderToNodeStream. There are two libraries that I know of that you can use. Check out:

- `react-helmet-async`*
- `react-safety-helmet`

*Though the documentation for `react-helmet-async` has a quick guide on how to use the library with renderToNodeStream, the author recently said it's not officially supported (@see https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async/issues/37#issuecomment-573361267)

Additionally, I see the `Loadable.preloadAll` function call - you're going to also have to migrate over to `loadable-components` which supports renderToNodeStream.

So, assuming you migrate over to `loadable-components` and one of the helmet libraries above, if your Head / helmet data is static, I believe everything should work for you right out of the box. If you have head data that depends on API calls, you might want to look into adding something like `react-ssr-prepass`.

I personally ended up using `react-safety-helmet`; here's the basic approach I took:

client

```
import { loadableReady } from '@loadable/component';
import { createHelmetStore, HelmetProvider } from 'react-safety-helmet';

const helmetStore = createHelmetStore();

loadableReady(() => {
  const root = document.getElementById('app-root')
  hydrate(
    <HelmetProvider store={helmetStore}
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routeContext}>
                <App/>
            </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
    </HelmetProvider>, root)
})
```

server

```
import { renderToNodeStream } from 'react-dom/server';
import { ChunkExtractor } from '@loadable/server';
import { createHelmetStore, HelmetProvider } from 'react-safety-helmet';

const statsFile = path.resolve('../dist/loadable-stats.json')

const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile })

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const helmetStore = createHelmetStore();
    let body = '';
    const router = (
      <HelmetProvider store={helmetStore}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routeContext}>
                    <App/>
                </StaticRouter>
            </Provider>
        </HelmetProvider>,
    );
    renderToNodeStream(router)
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve({
          body,
          helmet: helmetStore.renderStatic(),
        });
      });
}).then(({body, helmet}) => {
    // Create html with body and helmet object
    const linkTags = extractor.getLinkTags();
    const styleTags = extractor.getStyleTags();

    // This will be dependent on your implementation
    const htmlStates = {
        helmet, // From the resolved promise above
        store: store.getState(),
        linksTags,
        styleTags
    };

    const [startHtml, endHtml] = htmlTemplate(htmlStates); // Will vary on your implementation

    res.write(startHtml);
    res.write(body) // From the resolved promise above
    res.end(`${extractor.getScriptTags()}${endHtml}`) // This will vary as well - just make sure to add your JS tags before the closing </body></html>
});
```

Hopefully this helps get you on the right path. Best of luck.

Comment: hi! for ssr in react i'm using `react-helmet-async` , `loadable-component` , `react-router-dom` , `material-ui` so there are some sheet collectors  and ofcourse `express.js`. i tried your code and it works but i still get the error of initial response time in page speed insights and my score got worse .i donno how to make it so i could get the first response faster .in other words i donno how to get my response in stream manner and get little bytes continuously in order to increase my performance .thank u in advance @Jon Eric Escobedo

Comment: when i saw the decrease in performance i moved back to using renderToStaticMarkup .but as i said there is high loss of score on initial response time .the other matter is that i'm getting a re-render when it finishes ssr and starts csr .so it blinks and creates a not so awesome user experience . i'd be glad to here any solution i could try.

Comment: here is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050007/react-ssr-blinks-when-starting-client) for more info and help